# WifiNINA WebServer not receiving connections

Tags: wifi, mkr1010

I use a MKR 1010 (firmware 1.2.1), download WifiNINA library (version 1.3.0) and started to play with it.

I can connect to my Wifi network, and WifiNINA library examples such a WifiPing (which repeatedly pings www.google.com) works fine.

However, I can't get any of the server examples (e.g. WifiWebServer) to work.

I can see that the board connects to the network and gets an IP and the Serial monitor is printing this :

```
09:11:15.989 -> SSID: OfficeNet
09:11:15.989 -> IP Address: 192.168.1.44
09:11:15.989 -> signal strength (RSSI):-36 dBm
09:11:15.989 -> To see this page in action, open a browser to http://192.168.1.44
```

But if I browser to http://192.168.1.44, I never get any answer.

The loop code is just from the example :

```
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client)
  {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
(...)
  }
  // close the connection:
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("client disonnected");
}
```

I am never getting inside the `if client()`loop ("new client" never printed).

Any suggestions?

Comment: on what port do you start the server? didn't you forget to call server.begin()?

Comment: This is the out-of-the-box example code, so port 80, and server.begin() is on the last line of setup()

Comment: is your computer on the same WiFi network?

Comment: Yes, same network "OfficeNet". I did some more tests, the arduino can ping google server, but no computer from my network (I tried with 2 of them - and they can ping each other). I forced fixed IP address for all of them, no change...

Comment: is the network mask 255.255.255.0 or is it different?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Juraj ! Not sure how to check this. In my TCP/IP configuration there is something I would translate by "sub-network" which value is indeed 255.255.255.0. It is now quite late in my time zone. I'll go to sleep and delete/re-install everything tomorrow.

Comment: yes I meant sub-network mask. it determines which IP addresses 'see' each other. in case of 255.255.255.0 all addresses with the same first 3 numbers of IP address should be able to communicate

Comment: Dawn ! I deleted the whole Arduino IDE and re-installed everything yesterday night, and I got it working without any modification ! I even could ping any machine from my network. Switch off everything, came back this morning, and same problem again. Nothing works...